# Prestashop 1.6 How to totally disable Delivery Address form in Guest Checkout?

Tags: prestashop

Please help, totally confused..

On every step I get **errors**.

What `contollers/models/tpls` I should change to solve that issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need it because you sell virtual goods, my opinion is you should simply hide it from sigh and drop in dummy data. For example, if you use opc, edit order-opc-new-account.tpl, and wrap the content under

```
 <h3 class="page-subheading top-indent">{l s='Delivery address'}</h3>
```

in a hidden div. If you can't use a hidden one, try setting its height to 0. The fill in each of the contained fields with dummy data. I used it on my site till it started generating issues with paypal checkout mismatch in the address

Comment: This sounds simple, but introduces a lot of issues. E.g. that this dummy data will be visible in all emails, in the invoice and some payment methods like Paypal.

Comment: Yes, correct, I think there is no simpler method but this. Then it's about hiding identity pages to the end user, and not submitting an address to PP by editing that module as well... definitely complex